# Debug Into MFC Code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have build my application in release mode with debug information enabled. But I cannot debug into the MFC code for eg: CDocument::SetPathName

What should I do to step into MFC code in release mode?

Comment: There is no difference for finding the MFC source in debug or release mode. Do you get any messages?

Comment: There is nothing like that,  there should be a problem with the build.  Try to rebuild and check

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You haven't provided details how exactly you "have build my application in release mode with debug information enabled" or even what version of VS you are using. You may need to specify that you want debugging info both in compiler and linker sections of your project settings.